# mLab MongoDB connection always timeout via NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mlab

I'm trying to connect to mLab MongoDB database through NodeJS webapp, with this main code:

```
var express= require('express');
var app=express();
var mongoose=require('mongoose');
var config=require('./config');
var apiMain=require('./controllers/apiMain');
var timeout = require('connect-timeout');
app.use(timeout('10s'));
var port=process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

mongoose.connect(config.getDbConnString(), { useMongoClient: true });
mongoose.Promise=global.Promise;
var db=mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console,'errore di connessione'));

apiMain(app);

app.listen(port);
```

The connection string (get by the config file) **is correct** and I get **no compiling errors**.

By the way, every time I try to run it with **nodemon app** I get this error

```
errore di connessione { Error: read ETIMEDOUT
    at _errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:615:25) name: 'MongoError', message: 'read ETIMEDOUT' }
Unhandled rejection Error: read ETIMEDOUT
    at _errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:615:25)
```

I suppposed to increase timeout to more than 10 seconds: of course, it doesn't work too.

Comment: Most probably its because you are not passing the right username/password. check if you can connect to db without password `mongo mydb`

Comment: No.
As I said before I controlled **several times** them and they are **correct**.

And no: It won't connect without password too.

Comment: Hey Lorenzo, sorry to hear you're having issues. This could be a network problem. Are you also having issues trying to connect with the mongo shell command? If so, can you confirm that the database port is open on your network? You can see instructions for this and other troubleshooting steps in the mLab documentation: http://docs.mlab.com/connecting/#help

Comment: I've the same issues. But... I can say that @tfogo it was a port problem. This banking's network didn't respond anything about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having tried with different solution (like reinstalling the whole npm in the project), I get out from the problem.

Node, doesn't give you any information about locked port, and it was **the problem**: I tried to figure it out using another connection.

My PC (a Mac), hasn't any firewall and no locked port: the wireless company has it.

I got this solution, trying to ping the mlab server through CLI.